# Using different gmail,hotmail etc at the same time in a browser (Firefox)

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, cookies, browsing

What would be the best way to use different Gmail, StackExchange, Hotmail accounts etc. at the same time?

Currently I use different browsers (Firefox and Chrome) for different purposes.  Another technique could be to have several (Windows) user accounts.  I think some browsers permits different profiles.

It should be as transparent as possible.  I think I could achieve this by Firefox syncing tools like Lastpass (between different profiles/accounts).

Comment: there's multiple gmail account sign in if you want . http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/topic.py?hl=en&topic=28776

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd like to use multiple profiles with firefox this is easy. There is a built-in Profile Manager:
http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_manager#Windows

Comment: I can't see hwo to run different profiles at the same time?

Comment: You can use the -no-remote parameter: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Command_line_arguments#List_of_command_line_arguments_.28incomplete.29

Comment: Seems to be better than different user accounts for most purposes.

Comment: One problem I have is separating the different profiles, I can use theming, but the icons in the Windows taskbar look the same.